# How can I set a custom SSLSocketFactory on a Heroku app?

Tags: java, heroku, sslsocketfactory

I'd like to control which public IP addresses my app can connect to, so that I can blacklist a small set of IPs for outgoing connections for the entire app.

Deploying a Tomcat Java app to Heroku, I've specified a custom Java security configuration by overriding "java.security.properties"

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.properties=java.security -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

In that config, I've given a custom SSLSocketFactory class

```
ssl.SocketFactory.provider=security.MyCustomSocketFactory
```

This allows MyCustomSocketFactory to examine every IP address and host for outgoing connections in a small sample app. However, it's not working for my full application after I deploy to Heroku. The class isn't found, even though it is packaged into the .war file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: security.MyCustomSocketFactory
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
 at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:105)
 at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:335)
 at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:292)
```

I think I have to specify that my single class is class-loaded differently, because my application is initialized by webapp-runner.jar. Is there a different approach I should be taking?

I know my class is available to some classloader, because I can call `Class.forName()` from my own code, without getting an exception. But it's just not able to be loaded from `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`.

Comment: Maybe the class needs to be on the classpath outside of the war? Can you try adding a `Procfile` with: `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.properties=java.security -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar webapp.runner.launch.Main --port $PORT target/*.war`

Comment: You've got it! Thank you for pointing me down this path. I'll write up my final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [codefinger suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054561/how-can-i-set-a-custom-sslsocketfactory-on-a-heroku-app?noredirect=1#comment94946308_54054561) in a comment, I needed to include MyCustomSocketFactory on the classpath outside of the war file.

I moved MyCustomSocketFactory to a separate Maven project, and built it as a separate jar.

Then, I added a built step on my main project to copy the JAR into the same directory as webapp-runner.jar.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-socketblocker</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/dependency</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>jars</directory>
                        <includes>socketblocker-1.0.jar</includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Finally, I modified my Procfile to use wildcard matching, and add both webapp-runner.jar and my custom JAR as classpath entries.

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.properties=java.security -cp "target/dependency/*" webapp.runner.launch.Main --port $PORT target/*.war
```